# c++ While loop not terminating properly when filling an array, would like help exiting this loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, while-loop

I am currently trying to fill a double array with a while loop with a terminating condition (entered>0). The array is getting filled and the loop appears to be working however when a -1 is entered the program does not seem to exit the loop. I've been trying to debug this with cout statements for hours and I really appreciate any help.

```
double calc(double a[],double dev[], int n,double *mean);
void letter(double a[],char letg[],double std,double *mean);

int main(void)
{double a[6],dev[6],mean, std;
int i,n;
int entered;
char letg[6];

cout<<"Please enter the test grades one at a time (max 6)\n";
cout<<"enter a -1 when you are done entering scores\n";
//based off class notes
i=0;
cin>>entered; 
while (entered>0 && i<=6)
{a[i]=entered;
i++; 
cin>>entered;
}
i=n
cout<<"out of loop";
std=calc(a,dev,n,&mean);
letter(a,letg,std,&mean);
cout<<"the corresponding scores and letter grades are:\n";
 cout<<a;
cout<<letg;
return 0;
}

double calc(double a[],double dev[],int n,double *mean)
{int c,i;
cout<<"in calc";
double sum,sqdif,std;
c=0;
sum=0;
while (c<=n)
{sum=sum+a[c];
c++;
}
*mean=sum/(n+1);
for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
dev[n]=pow((a[n]-*mean),2);

for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
sqdif=dev[i]+sqdif;
std=sqrt(sqdif/c);
return std;
}
```

Comment: `<= 6` should be `< 6`, indices in an array of size 6 go from 0 to 5.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but a core dump is still occurring when a -1 is imputed.

Comment: Do `cout<<"out of loop"<<endl;` to see if the output is simply getting lost before the core dump.

Comment: stackoverflow should provide a big red button for C++ questions regarding istreams, not testing for successful extractions

Comment: I am now getting the "out of loop"! Still am getting a core dump so im going to try to add some more cout statements

Comment: I tried entering 3 scores, worked fine. 6 scores, worked fine. 7 scores and you get a buffer overrun (because of <=6) which corrupts a variable and will cause your segv. Recommend giving us your test data (numbers you enter in sequence)

Comment: I am now able to exit the array but the core dump seems to be occurring during a function call now, i am adding more of the code.

Comment: `std=calc(a,dev,n,&mean);` <== `n` is uninitialized when this is called. Turn up your compiler warnings and fix *everything* that is flagged. Edit: Now with `i=n` added, the value of `i` is lost and *both* `i` and `n` are indeterminate. SO isn't an online interactive debugging site. And changing your posted code instead of adding *updated* code relegates all answers and comments concerning prior versions utterly meaningless.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have understood that the wrong indexing pointed out by Borleader can trigger a segfault AT ANY MOMENT and not necessarily at the moment you store the number in the array... can you confirm that now you loop on i<6  ?

Comment: So the array is stored and can be printed outside the loop, The loop will terminate both when a -1 is inputted or when 6 numbers have been entered. So can i not pinpoint the location of my problem with cout statements?

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be negative numbers (sizing problem). try another positive number for exit e.g. 99
also try the same code with an exit controlled loop i.e. do..while

Answer (score 0):

After you'll have solved the problem with `i<6` (instead of `i<=6` which causes the segfault as Borgleader pointed out 1),  correct this one:

```
double entered;   // should be double and not int
```

With `entered` declared at int `int`,  if you enter a floating point number, for example 0.5,  it will stop reading at the dot (because dot is not valid for an integer), and never be able to read all the other numbers that you'll type.

***Suggestion:*** It could be a good practice to check for valid input, for example by replacing the `cin>entered;` with:

```
    // cin>>entered; => if wrong input, you'll not do anything about it
    while (!(cin >> test) && cin.fail() && ! cin.eof()) {  // check if  input failed, and for another reason that an eof. 
        cout << "Wrong input. Enter again ! ";
        cin.clear();    // reset error flag
        cin.ignore(SIZE_MAX, '\n');  // discard faulty input
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the input sequence you have given. Its getting out of the loop when I tried

Comment: If u are inputting decimal numbers then use **double** instead of **int** for entered

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps move away from arrays and instead use a vector:

```
int main(void)
{
    std::vector<double> scoreList; 
    double score;

    // Intro msg
    std::cout << "Please enter the test grades one at a time (max 6)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "enter a -1 when you are done entering scores" << std::endl;

    // Loop for up to 6 scores, exit loop when 6 entered.
    while (scoreList.size() < 6)
    {
        std::cin >> score;

        // Exit loop if -1 entered
        if (score == -1.0)
            break;

        scoreList.push_back(score);
    }

    // Access scores and display
    for (std::vector<double>::iterator v = scoreList.begin(); v != scoreList.end(); v++)
        std::cout << "Score entered: " << *v << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is no buffer overrun and all that is needed is to iterate through the list of entered numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize variables before assigning them.

```
i=n      //n = ?
```

and

```
sqdif=dev[i]+sqdif;       //sqdif = ?
```

Consider this example about Uninitialized variables error -

```html
int main() {
   int i;
   return i;   // C4700
}
```